# return from navigation in react native give me undefined in this.props.navigation.state.params.filePath

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

i need help :).
my project is 2 pages in react native, MainPage and SoundRecord.
my init screen is MainPage and when i press the button 'take sound'
i move to another component to record sound(i move with react native navigation).
when i come back i want to return the filePath(where it save the file..).
i want to insert it to the state.

when i do this in MainPage:

```
this.state{
filePath: this.props.navigation.state.params.filePath
}
```

it give error:
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.filePath')
and i understand this because i start my project with MainPage and i dont have the filePath from the SoundRecord page.

what can i do?
can i do check if this.props.navigation.state.params.filePath !== undefined?
how to do it? i try almost everything...

i put the relevant code:

MainPage:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';
import { aws } from './keys';
import SoundRecord from './SoundRecord'

  export default class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            file:'' ,
            config:'',
            filePath: '',
            fileName: '',
            tag:''
        };
      }
  MoveToSoundRecordPage = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SoundRecord');
  }
  render() {
        return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.MoveToSoundRecordPage}>
          <Text>take sound</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* <SoundRecord takeSound={this.takeSound}/> */}
        <Text>{this.state.fileName}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.UploadToAWS.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Upload To Aws</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

SoundRecord when i finish to record i send the filePath like this:

```
finishRecord = (filePath) => {
this.props.navigation.navigate('MainPage',{filePath});
```

}

thank!

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation`?

Comment: react-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update something on the previous page then you can do it in the following way.

1. Create a function in the `MainPage` that updates the state with the new filepath.
2. Pass the function as as a param.
3. Use the passed function in `SoundRecord` to update the state in the `MainPage`

## MainPage

In your `MainPage` add the following

```
sendFilepath = (filePath) => {
  this.setState({filePath})
}
```

Update the `MoveToSoundRecordPage` function to take the sendFilepath as a parameter:

```
MoveToSoundRecordPage = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('SoundRecord', { sendFilepath: this.sendFilepath });
}
```

## SoundRecord

Then in the `SoundRecord` page you want to update the `finishRecord` so that it calls the function that you have passed.

```
finishRecord = (filePath) => {
  this.props.navigation.state.params.sendFilepath(filePath)
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

## Snack

Here is a snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/navigation-passing-function that shows passing a function called `sendFilepath` from `Screen1` to `Screen2`. Then in `Screen2` it then calls the function that was passed and this updates the state in `Screen1`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It may help you

Add this in **MainPage screen:**

```
componentWillMount() {
  const filePath = this.props.navigation.getParam('filePath', '');
  this.setState({ filePath:filePath })
}
```

Comment: when componentWillMount() should run? it is not work.. when i go back from SoundRecord to MainPage nothing happen...